# Power ratings for micro JST

Tags: current, maximum-ratings

I am just trying to figure out the max current which i could expose my new micro JST cables to. It says [here](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSH.pdf) that they are rated for 1A and 50V. Converted to power that would be 50W. that sounds very high for such thin wire. Am I understanding the ratings correctly? Could the current be increased if the voltage was reduced? Many thanks.

Comment: The 50V rating indicates how much voltage different conductors in the cable can have without risking breaking down.  You won't have 50V across any of the conductors.  The cable is capable of delivering about 50W, not dissipating it itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, your understanding is not correct and you can't increase the current at lower voltages.

The current rating is the maximum current that can pass through the connector without damaging the connector. This would be limited by the inherent current-carrying ability of the conducting parts of the connector. The voltage rating indicates the maximum voltage **difference** that can safely appear continuously between two conductors in the connector...a higher voltage would require more spacing and/or better insulation between conductors. So, these limits are not telling you how much power can be dissipated within the connector.

You must satisfy **both** limits all the time.

Comment: Is the voltage rating to avoid electrical arcing between pins?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what determines the voltage rating, but it in some way relates to the connector's safety.

Answer (score 0):

No, the current rating already defines the maximum current the cable/connector can conduct. The 50V defines the widthstand voltage or isolation voltage that can be applied between two pins safely.